# Laravel 4 - Autoload Laravel classes in custom controller namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, autoload, autoloader

a quick (maybe stupid) question.

I'm using a namespace for my controllers, like so:

```
namespace Members;

use DB;
use Input;
use PerformanceReport;
use Redirect;

class AdminController extends MembersController {
```

And as expected, I have to provide use statements for the Laravel classes I wish to use.

From what I've understood, the composer autoloader prevents this from being necessary if used correctly.

So my question being, is it possible to configure the autoloader to suit my needs, and if so, how would I go by doing this?

Comment: If you use the correct namespace and you use the default Laravel project, you should be fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What do you mean by correct namespace and default Laravel project?

Comment: @TristanGodfrey, your question is not clear, can you please reword it ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera How can I use Laravel classes in a custom namespace without having to provide use statements for each class? (as demonstrated in my question)

Comment: with composer you can auto load packages and classes. Please check this video for auto-load classes https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading

Answer (score 3):

Your question is connected with the way PHP namespaces work, not with composer's autoloader.

If your class is in `namespace Controllers;` and you'd write `Redirect::to('/')` php would assume that the class you're referring to is in the current declared namespace (in that case Controllers/Redirect). You can either write `\Redirect::to('/')` or put a `use Redirect` statement on top like you did.

Composer's autoload just maps namespaces to their file directory (see `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` for how it maps it).

If you want to dive more into composer's autoloading, i'd recommend read up on PSR-0 and PSR-4.